# Is this the correct way of updating the page after an AJAX request?

Tags: php, jquery

I've successfully made it so a user can comment through AJAX in order to avoid page refreshing, however, I wasn't exactly sure what is the correct way to display the new database records back on the page so I went with this:

```
$('.postComment').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var userId = $("input[name=user_id]").val();
        var imageId = $("input[name=image_id]").val();
        var comment = $("textarea[name=comment]").val();

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlComment,
            data: {userId: userId, imageId: imageId, comment: comment, _token: token}
        }).done(function(){
            $("textarea[name=comment]").val("");
            $('.comments').append('<p>'+comment+'</p>');   
        })
    });
```

After the AJAX request is done, I remove what is written in the text field and append a new paragraph with the comment that was uploaded to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is available in done callback as first argument

```
.done(function(serverResponseData){ 
   /* do something with response data*/
})
```

If it is html you can put that html anywhere you want using any jQuery insertion method.

If it is JSON, or XML, iterate through it and wrap various values parsed from it in html to insert into DOM